# Adding map<pair<int,int>,vector<Object> > into BST where pair is key

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, maps, binary-search-tree

So I have a map where the key is pair of month and year  and value returned is vector, which is basically a vector of weather instances for that very month/year.

NOTE: BST is made by me and not the STL BST.

```
for (map<pair<int, int>, vector<Weather> >::iterator it = monthMap.begin(); it != monthMap.end(); ++it)
{
    month = it->first.first;
    year = it->first.second;
    monthVec = it->second;
    monthBST.Insert(map<make_pair(month,year),monthVec>);
}
```

However, its returning a bunch of errors, all relating to how I cant have any of that in a constant expression (make_pair, month, year, function call, monthVec)

```
main.cpp|170|error: 'std::make_pair(_T1, _T2)' cannot appear in a constant-expression|
main.cpp|170|error: 'month' cannot appear in a constant-expression|
main.cpp|170|error: 'year' cannot appear in a constant-expression|
main.cpp|170|error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression|
main.cpp|170|error: 'monthVec' cannot appear in a constant-expression|
main.cpp|170|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
main.cpp|170|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
main.cpp|170|error: template argument 3 is invalid|
main.cpp|170|error: template argument 4 is invalid|
```

I tried a bunch of things, can't seem to figure it out.

End goal is to have a BST, which will self-balance (since sorted data), and the key is found, it returns the monthVec associated to it.

Comment: Don't paraphrase error messages, copy and paste them.

Comment: @molbdnilo Right, will edit it in now.

Comment: `map` is a class template, and `map<make_pair(month,year),monthVec>` (if it existed) would be a type, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like you want something like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<Weather>> WeatherMap; 

// for (const auto& itr : monthMap) // This is a bit cleaner
for (auto itr = monthMap.begin(); itr != monthMap.end(); ++it)
{
    WeatherMap newMap;
    newMap.insert(*itr);
    monthBST.Insert(std::move(newMap));
}
```

This doesn't make a ton of sense given your explanation, so you might actually want something like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<Weather>> WeatherMap; 

for (auto itr = monthMap.begin(); itr != monthMap.end(); ++it)
{
    monthBST.Insert(*itr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use multimap, when you need multiple values to be the key.